# VSIX: standalone package

Tags: vsix

My VSIX package uses a bunch of images and third-party dlls, and when compiled the Release folder contains all of that stuff in the raw form. Looks really bad. Is there any way to create a standalone vsix file I could redistribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should also be a .vsix file in the bin\Release folder that contains all the other files. You can rename it to .zip and view the contents in Windows Explorer to inspect it.

When you install that .vsix on a machine, it should also drop all the other 'loose' files you're talking about into the extension install folder.

Comment: You're right, giving out vsix file only is enough! That's brilliant! I wonder how that works inside VS. If I include log4net 1.2.10 and someone else's extension includes log4net 1.3.0 will that cause any conflicts?

Comment: Yes, it could. Ideally, there would be a shared log4net VSIX that your extension depends on that makes the assembly available at runtime.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997168.aspx